# wireless enabled but can't browse internet

Tags: networking, wifi, networkmanager

My laptop sees wireless ssid and connects but I get unknown host when trying to ping www.google.co.za, but I get replies when I ping 8.8.8.8, my other machine connected to the same router can surf the net no problems. I have tried adding nameserver but the laptop keeps loosing the configurations every now and then. Please help!

`/etc/resolf.conf` after I added `nameserver 8.8.8.8` by hand:

```
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver 127.0.0.1
```

Comment: Please provide more information, for example a routing table. Are you using NetworkManager as the tag implies? That might be overwriting your configuration set by hand.

Comment: I have a normal ADSL router which is connected to telkom line and getting my IP from service provider. I use cat5 on the rest of the machines and wireless on this specific laptop. My connection is normal IP from ISP and therefore I attached machines to a normal ADSL router, my routing is not complicated. Hope this answers the question Peterph. Could that still be overwritting my config file?

Comment: Oh, sorry I misread your question - routing doesn't seem to be the problem indeed. I believe NM could be overwriting your setup. What does your `/etc/resolf.conf` look like?

Comment: # Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver 127.0.0.1 - this is after I edited my file and added nameserver 8.8.8.8

Comment: Next time please add it into the question (using the `edit` button. :) As you can see, it even tells you that any changes will be lost. I'm afraid we'll need to know more about what distribution (end version) you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Which OS do you work with?
If it's Ubuntu, check out this link:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/2321/what-is-the-proper-way-to-change-the-dns-ip

If not, you may still be able to adapt the steps to your system...
I think it's not as easy as just editing `/etc/resolv.conf` on your machine. I think it will be overwritten by Networkmanager.
As an alternative, you could possibly disable Networkmanager and work with the "old" `ifup` and `ifdown` scripts, but you might use some comfort like automatic WiFi network selection and so on...

Comment: Thanks TomS, I have done all this steps in GUI and on terminal - but no matter what I do, the nameserver get scratched from /etc/resolv.conf file. Any idea what else to do!!!

Comment: Oooopsss! I am running Linux Mint 13 Maya \n \l

Comment: how many network connections do you use? One? more? What are the exact settings for the DNS server for each of the network connections?

Comment: I've got three more machines on the network and the dns servers on them are 10.0.0.2. I have tried the same IP on this laptop and it just ignores it. My route -n are pointing to the same Ip and 8.8.8.8

Comment: what are the contents of what does `cat /etc/resolv.conf` say? What does `nm-tool | grep -i dns` show?